# Как заменить произвольный текст регуляркой в середине строки?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Как заменить текст в строке: `***** RUB ***` на `sum1`?

Валидацию это регулярное выражение в онлайн проверках проходит, а вот в БД не могу поменять.

Текст: `***** RUB ***` всегда разный.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('Оплата ***** RUB *** Никому не говорите
код **', '(?<=Оплата\ ).*(?=\ Никому)', 'sum1')
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*lookahead / lookbehind* не поддерживаются в Oracle.

Попробуйте так ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e794a8ea02ba7f55054f6a618fa0a917)):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE (
    'Оплата ***** RUB *** Никому не говорите код **', 
    '(^Оплата\s+).*(\s+Никому)', '\1sum1\2') res
from dual
/

RES
-------------------------------------
Оплата sum1 Никому не говорите код **
```